# using multi level Auto complete in search query

Tags: jquery, html, autocomplete

I would like to build a search engine where users can enter a question in the form of a verb + noun, to optimize the experience I would like to have the user first be offered auto complete on the verb, and then according to the selected verb, be offered matching nouns.

for example

I am looking for someone who can : ***_*__*_*___**
and now the user starts typing after the :

for example if he types ki -> kick, kill, kiss, and on the basis of the choice of the first work the second work would suggest only nouns that are suitable to the first

for kick -> football, ball, etc

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have a database where you store the relationships between verbs and their relevant nouns? Coding the auto-complete functionality is fairly straight forward with jQuery and something like the autocomplete plugin. The difficult part will be supplying the data to make the thing actually useful.